# Convert C# DateTime while in "let"?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert the DateTime in an array to something JavaScript understands as a valid date so I can chart the results. I'm using the following code to build an array from another object:

```
let arr = obj.map(e => {
    let { dateTime, averageJitterInMs } = e;
    return [dateTime, +averageJitterInMs];
});
```

The source date example is stored as UTC time: `2018-10-14T17:19:53.2596293`

I've tried:

```
let arr = obj.map(e => {
    let { dateTime, averageJitterInMs } = e;
    return [function() { return new Date(dateTime) }, +averageJitterInMs];
});
```

this gives me zeros for date...

Also tried:

```
let arr = obj.map(e => {
    let { dateTime, averageJitterInMs } = e;
    return [function() { new Date(dateTime) }, +averageJitterInMs];
});
```

this also gives me zeros...

Also tried:

```
let arr = obj.map(e => {
    let { dateTime, averageJitterInMs } = e;
    return [Date.parse(dateTime), +averageJitterInMs];
});
```

this gives me epoch time I believe which isn't what I'm after.

Obviously my syntax for using an anonymous function is incorrect among other things. Just looking for a little help on the proper way to do this or if it can be done inside this let block.

Also, given the date format, do I need to perform additional action on it to interpret the 'time' value in the string? I have the option of formatting the string as I wish from the back-end before it hits the JavaScript (i.e. through my C# code). So if it makes sense to do it there so it's easier for JavaScript to parse it, no problem.

Comment: `return [new Date(dateTime), +averageJitterInMs]` ? And I would just pass milliseconds since 1970 as that is the only thing `Date()` parses reliably.

Comment: I had inconsistent results from. Microsoft Edge using `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US')` and a c sharp date string like what the OP has. Edge produced an output that included the timezone while Firefox and Chrome just produced a short date. So in the end I split the date string manually to get the day, month and year and have that build a new date object

Comment: @JonasWilms that was it! Thanks. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `Date` constructor:

```
 return [new Date(dateTime), +averageJitterInMs]
```

> [I could change the format] if it makes sense to do it, so that it's easier for JavaScript to parse it

I would just pass milliseconds since 1970 as that is the only thing Date() parses reliably